# same software different versions?

Tags: apt, 20.04

I have a strange problem. It looks something like version conflict. I mean I have an installed package with a specific version, but the software installed is an other version. But they should the same. For example I have vlc package installed and the package version and the software are the same version. for example:

```
$ vlc --version | grep ^VLC
VLC media player 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (revision 3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)
VLC versione 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)
$ apt-show-versions vlc
vlc:amd64/focal 3.0.9.2-1 uptodate
vlc:i386 not installed
```

But I have ublock-origin addon for firefox that the versions doesn't match, look:

```
$ apt-show-versions webext-ublock-origin xul-ext-ublock-origin
webext-ublock-origin:all/focal 1.22.2+dfsg-1 uptodate
xul-ext-ublock-origin:all/focal 1.22.2+dfsg-1 uptodate
```

But as you see the version is different:

[image: screenshot showing version 1.9.15.101]

Why?

Comment: Releases com with the version at the time of their release. Only security updates change that for most of them. There are exceptions like browser, of course.

Comment: The fields come from two different sources: `vlc --version` queries VLC internally, and it's up to a developer to increment that version. `apt-show-versions` merely checks the version number in the Debian control file, which is set by somebody else at a different time and place. Debian and Ubuntu often modify that external version number (`1.22.2+dfsg-1`) to differentiate between different VCS pulls, different uploads, or patches to fix bugs. Those are normal package maintenance that may occur between upstream releases.

Comment: @user535733 you mean that the software has a version, but the package can has a different version ?
If yes, is there a way to know the real versione of the software ?

Comment: No, random people do not assign random version numbers. There's a sensible method to it.  Here's an example: Upstream software releases Foo v1.2. Debian applies a couple patches, and calls it it v1.2+dfsg-3. Ubuntu applies a security update and calls it v1.2+dfsg-3ubuntu1. You ask the software, it says "I'm version 1.2". And it actually is version 1.2...plus a couple patches. "Real version" leads to [Ship-of-Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) confusion. Take the upstream version and subsequent patches for what they are.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the `ublock` version that has been packaged in the Ubuntu software repositories. That version is unlikely to be updated during the life time of your Ubuntu version, unless some severe security issue would emerge and packagers would be notified and take action.

If it works, I would suggest: do not break. Still, to install the latest version of the addon, you could install it from the addons.mozilla.org website. First remove the systemwide installed extension: `sudo apt remove webext-ublock-origin xul-ext-ublock-origin` (the latter package does not anymore exist on Ubuntu 21.10 and up). Then, in Firefox, use the "Addons manager" to install the extension directly from the website.

Answer (score -2):

Your doing are two totally different things with two totally different things. It doesn't surprise me that the results are inconsistent. With Linux it is very important to know with certaintly the exact version of a package, or the whole system can break.

With firefox it is not at all important to know the exact version of an add-on. If there's an error along the line, it can be corrected at any time.

EDIT: I missed that the mozilla add-on was actually packaged for the distro. I've never installed an add-on that way. But thje git repo has nothing to do with the distro package, at least as far as versions go.

My humble opinion says you don't have a lot to worry about in regards to your question. If you don't understand something about my answer, please leave a comment.

Comment: If I understand you mean that the package can have a versione and the internal software an other version. If so, is there a way to know the internal versione of the software from apt or dpkg ? Without checking manually the version with -v or searching inside the package.

Comment: I don't think this explains why an apt-installed browser extension would be newer than the version than Firefox reports. There are probably a few theories but "just ignore it" doesn't explain it.